# How to boot after adding a drive which gets assigned sda?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, fstab, plymouth

I run Ubuntu 18.04 on dual UEFI boot with Windows 10. I have one SSD (both systems are on that one) and one HDD. After adding a brand new SSD the new SSD got assigned sda and the system booted into emergency mode.

Program `plymouthd` was sending SIGRTMIN (as observed by examining the journal by `journalctl -xb`).

After removal of the new SSD Ubuntu is working as normal. Windows 10 was not affected by this.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: What SATA port are you using. Best to start with SATA0 and add each drive in order. And normally SATA0 will be assigned to hd0 in grub/UEFI and then Ubuntu will see it as sda.  If new NVMe drive that may not be the case.

Comment: When you say "doesn't boot", what exactly happens? How are you able to run `journalctl`? Is it that it boots you to "emergency mode"? If so: "emergency mode" almost always means a mount failure. You can use `systemctl --state=failed` to see the list of failed units; I would look at the `.mount` units first. Also, you can use `mount -a` to try mounting all the filesystems in `/etc/fstab` and see if there is a helpful error message.

Comment: @sourcejedi sorry, I meant emergency mode. I will edit the question not to be confusing.

Comment: @sourcejedi I think there was an error message along the lines the device was busy.

I have since migrated the filesystem to the new SSD which was the goal and can't reproduce the error anymore. Everything works for me now but I would still like to know how to solve this issue in the case I would encounter it in the future.

Comment: @VaNa this should not happen normally. But you might reach emergency mode if you had a line in `/etc/fstab` which was hardcoded as `sda`.  To temporarily fix it, update `sda` to whatever. To avoid it in future, don't hardcode `sda`. Generally it's most robust to use `UUID=` in fstab, like the installer does. (But if you have to recover, it is quicker and easier to update the `sda` to whatever first, because you can't easily copy+paste a long UUID in emergency mode). However this should not show up as a "device busy" message. I can't tell what caused that message  or your problem.